# Finding if the hover/click happened within the custom legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a packed bubble chart in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0sdxab61/

I wanted to know if there is a way to find out, if the user is hovering/clicking on the center legend (`Europe ....`/`Long word....`). Right now, if we click/hover the center legend, the smaller bubbles tootltip is showen/click handler gets triggered. Is there a way to prevent and always show legend as tooltip when hover/clicked on it?

```js
(function(H) {
  H.addEvent(H.Series, 'afterDrawDataLabels', function(e) {
    const series = this;
    const chart = series.chart;

    if (!series.parentNode.plotX || chart.options.chart.type !== 'packedbubble') {
      return;
    }

    if (!series.customLabel) {
      series.customLabel = series.chart.renderer.label(
          series.name, null, 'rect'
        )
        .attr({
          align: 'center',
          fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)',
          zIndex: 3,
          shape: 'rect'
        })
        .css({
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: '12px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          whiteSpace: 'nowrap', // To prevent text wrapping
          padding: '5px', // Add some padding around the label text
          borderRadius: '5px', // Add rounded corners to the background
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
          width: series.parentNode.graphic.width
        })
        .add();
    }

    series.customLabel.attr({
      x: series.parentNode.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
      y: series.parentNode.plotY + chart.plotTop - 10
    });
  });
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'packedbubble',
    height: '100%'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Carbon emissions around the world (2014)',
    align: 'left'
  },
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.value}m CO<sub>2</sub>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    packedbubble: {
      minSize: '20%',
                  events: {
              click: () => alert("hello"),
            },
      maxSize: '100%',
      zMin: 0,
      zMax: 1000,
      layoutAlgorithm: {
        gravitationalConstant: 0.05,
        splitSeries: true,
        seriesInteraction: false,
        dragBetweenSeries: true,
        parentNodeLimit: true
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}',
        filter: {
          property: 'y',
          operator: '>',
          value: 250
        },
        style: {
          color: 'black',
          textOutline: 'none',
          fontWeight: 'normal'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Europe 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222',
    data: [{
        name: 'Germany',
        value: 767.1
      }, {
        name: 'Croatia',
        value: 20.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Belgium',
        value: 97.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Czech Republic',
        value: 111.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Netherlands',
        value: 158.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Spain',
        value: 241.6
      },
      {
        name: 'Ukraine',
        value: 249.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Poland',
        value: 298.1
      },
      {
        name: 'France',
        value: 323.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Romania',
        value: 78.3
      },
      {
        name: 'United Kingdom',
        value: 415.4
      }, {
        name: 'Turkey',
        value: 353.2
      }, {
        name: 'Italy',
        value: 337.6
      },
      {
        name: 'Greece',
        value: 71.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Austria',
        value: 69.8
      },
      {
        name: 'Belarus',
        value: 67.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Serbia',
        value: 59.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Finland',
        value: 54.8
      },
      {
        name: 'Bulgaria',
        value: 51.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Portugal',
        value: 48.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Norway',
        value: 44.4
      },
      {
        name: 'Sweden',
        value: 44.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Hungary',
        value: 43.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Switzerland',
        value: 40.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Denmark',
        value: 40
      },
      {
        name: 'Slovakia',
        value: 34.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Ireland',
        value: 34.6
      },
      {
        name: 'Croatia',
        value: 20.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Estonia',
        value: 19.4
      },
      {
        name: 'Slovenia',
        value: 16.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Lithuania',
        value: 12.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Luxembourg',
        value: 10.4
      },
      {
        name: 'Macedonia',
        value: 9.5
      },
      {
        name: 'Moldova',
        value: 7.8
      },
      {
        name: 'Latvia',
        value: 7.5
      },
      {
        name: 'Cyprus',
        value: 7.2
      }
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Long word 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222 1234432222',
    data: [{
        name: 'Senegal',
        value: 8.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Cameroon',
        value: 9.2
      },
      {
        name: 'Zimbabwe',
        value: 13.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Ghana',
        value: 14.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Kenya',
        value: 14.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Sudan',
        value: 17.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Tunisia',
        value: 24.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Angola',
        value: 25
      },
      {
        name: 'Libya',
        value: 50.6
      },
      {
        name: 'Ivory Coast',
        value: 7.3
      },
      {
        name: 'Morocco',
        value: 60.7
      },
      {
        name: 'Ethiopia',
        value: 8.9
      },
      {
        name: 'United Republic of Tanzania',
        value: 9.1
      },
      {
        name: 'Nigeria',
        value: 93.9
      },
      {
        name: 'South Africa',
        value: 392.7
      }, {
        name: 'Egypt',
        value: 225.1
      }, {
        name: 'Algeria',
        value: 141.5
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I fully understand your requirements; however, the `legendItemClick` event that might be what you are looking for: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick 
Let me know if you need any help with the implementation!

Comment: @magdalena yeah I think I need to fire different when the center legend is clicked, instead of firing the small bubble click event (which is common for all)

Comment: @magdalena I tried https://jsfiddle.net/5eq4pywd/, I don't see the legend click console statements

Comment: I've taken a look, and in my case, the legend event displays statements in the console. Let me to organize the information for clarity. You can find the nomenclature for the chart elements in this image: https://ibb.co/QC04LGk. Considering that, would you mind sharing your requirements once again? Thanks!